# Custom DE. cairo-dock and Pcmanfm reset on logout?

Tags: lubuntu, reboot, pcmanfm, cairo

Using Lubuntu Latest...
I created a custom Desktop Environment using Openbox, cairo-dock and Pcmanfm...
I created mydesk.desktop in /usr/share/xsessions containing

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=WOWcool
Comment=Really Neat
Exec=/home/zorion10/mydesk
TryExec=/home/zorion10/mydesk
Type=XSession
```

And in /home/zorion10/mydesk

```
#!/bin/sh
cairo-dock &
pcmanfm -d --desktop &
compton -c --shadow-exclude 'n:e:cairo-dock' &
openbox
```

The problem is that neither cairo-dock nor pcmanfm save the configurations i make...

I deleted config files of PcManFM (~/zorion10/.config/PcManFm) and it did not create new ones until I used the default DE

Answer (score 1):

The answer was originally posted in [Revision #2](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/839263/2) of the question. For more details, see [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/839263/revisions).

> Changed the permissions of `~/.config/cairo-dock` and for PcManFm, I stopped using it and switched to nautilus